# What is this function for this graph?

Tags: functions

Trying to find a function like this:[image]

1. 2 y-axis asymptotes: -1 / 1
2. x values range from -infinity to infinity.

Comment: looks like $\arctan$, or maybe $\tanh$?

Comment: seems right. thanks! can you answer it?

Comment: It might as well be $y = \operatorname{erf}(x)$, or any S-shaped (sigmoid) function.

Comment: You can also study $f_n(x) = x(1+x^{2n})^{-\frac{1}{2n}}$ for different $n \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many functions having these properties. Here, for example, is the graph of

$$ f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(x) $$

[image: arctan]

Here is

$$ y=\frac{1-e^{-ax}}{1+e^{-ax}}\text{ for }a=1 $$

but you can let $a>0$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$

[image: exponential]

Answer (score 1):

Another which immediately comes to mind for me is a modified logistic function $f(x)=\frac{2}{1+e^{-x}}-1$. It looks like: [image: Logistic]